# C : Comparing 2 Strings

Tags: c, structure, strcmp

I have to compare 2 strings, one from a file, and one from a user input, here is the file:

```
Password 
abcdefg 
Star_wars 
jedi
Weapon 
Planet 
long 
nail 
car 
fast 
cover 
machine 
My_little
Alone
Love
Ghast
```

**The code for getting the string from the line is fine** but the code for comparing the 2 strings does not give the right output

```
int main(void){
  int loop, line;
  char str[512];
  char string[512];
  FILE *fd = fopen("Student Passwords.txt", "r");
  if (fd == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to open file\n");
    return -1;
  }
  printf("Enter the string: ");
  scanf("%s",string);
  printf("Enter the line number to read : ");
  scanf("%d", &line);

  for(loop = 0;loop<line;++loop){
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), fd);
  }
  printf("\nLine %d: %s\n", line, str);

  if(strcmp(string,str) == 0 ){
    printf("Match");
  }else{
    printf("No Match");
  }
  fclose(fd);
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Perhaps the str resets but i don't know, perhaps some of the talented programmers here can see the problem.

Anyone know what is wrong with my string comparison?

Correct output:
Input: jedi, 4 Output: Match

edit: Both strings are the same, in the same case
edit: dreamlax fixed this.

Comment: what do mean by adding a structure tag??

Comment: so, you mean, that `str` is `jedi` and `string` is `Jedi`? And the `strcmp` "fails"?

Comment: @invalid_id Maybe, Does it matter?

Comment: @user3227362 - it does, `strcmp` is case sensitive.

Comment: `strcmp()` compares strings case-sensitively, meaning `Jedi` and `jedi` are considered different. You need to use `strcasecmp()` if you want to compare strings disregarding case.

Comment: Jedi and jedi are obviously different as by the compiler.

Comment: Dammit the Jedi was a typo, it's changed and should be jedi

Comment: @user3227362: yes it matters, homework is meant to learn from, solving problems is one of those things you have to learn. Asking for a solution for problem won't help you solving the next problem.

Comment: @invalid_id Now i have the solution i can base my programs around it, remember coding is all about remembering when you have to learn it

Comment: @user3227362 imo coding is about solving problems/making life easier. If that's not the goal your code is useless

Comment: @invalid_id the best way to learn is by having the solution SHOWN to you with the method, it's like going to a maths lessons and the teacher telling you to stuff you have no idea how to do.

Comment: @user3227362 dream on, you have to gasp the concept of how to solve a problem. When you go to a math class they should tell you how to solve the problem, not show you all the solutions

Comment: @invalid_id If i don't have an solution, how am i supposed to know what form my other solutions should take?, And what if i go wrong?, i ask someone with more experiance, hence stack overflow

Comment: @user3227362 You could do search the package your using and think what might be a solution before asking for a solution. Nothing wrong with asking for a solution, but only if research and creativity couldn't fix it.

Comment: @invalid_id My Program is fixed and now works perfectly, now, if you don't mind i'm gonna wipe this questions exsistance off the face of the planet

Comment: @user3227362, be my guest.

Comment: @user3227362 - stop vandalising your questions by completely changing the question.  You're well on your way to an automated question ban if you keep this up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fgets()` does not discard any newline character after reading, so it will be part of `str`, which will cause the comparison to fail since `string` won't have a newline character. To get around this, you simply need to remove the newline character from `str`.

```
str[strlen(str) - 1] = '\0';
if (strcmp(string, str) == 0)
    // ...
```

Ideally, make sure `strlen(str) > 0` first, otherwise you will invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thank you, this works, the output is correct, when 6 minutes pass i'll happily accept the answer

Comment: @user3227362: No worries, this particular property of `fgets` has tripped me up before.